# how to specify gradle home in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to import a project from eclipse to android studio, when I imports it the it start downloading gradle bin files, but the download process never got completed, I downloaded the gradle bin manually, now I want to import it to my project, how this could be done?